# How do I redirect a node to a path followed by a wildcard?

Tags: 8, nodes, redirection

I have a basic page node that contains two views in block form. The views both contain contextual filters captured from the URL. How to I publish my node to allow the user to visit /report/2002, or /report/2004, or /report/2010. The blocks are configured to display on /report/*. How do I do the same for a node?

Do I need to make my own controller with custom routing?

Comment: A view with a page display instead of the block display would generate the route automatically.

Comment: So the solution is to generate one of the views as a page, and add the second view as a block to that page?

Comment: Yes, this would generate the wildcard route.

Comment: Go ahead and put it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view with a page display instead of the block display would generate the route automatically.

Comment: I had to add my second view into the footer of the first using the views configuration, in order to get both views on the one page.

Comment: In my use case, I found the view to be very slow. Changing to a controller significantly sped things up. It appears that views only queries for entity ids, then requeries for the fields of each entity of interest. My SQL statement pulls only the information I need in one query.